# How to make pop submenu stay visible when the mouse is outside the parents container and submenu when hover

Tags: css, popup, hover, position, mouseover

How do I enable the pop submenu to stay visible when the mouse hovers outside of its parent container or the submenu?

Currently, if the mouse doesn't slide straight down from the parent container (B) `.account-settings-container` to the submenus top arrow, the menu will not stay visible

Note that the issue occurs when the submenu is directly below the navigation bar. The tiny bit of spacing from the bottom padding of the navigation bar is what negates the submenu's visibility when hovering around that area but I need the nav padding to give the rows some room to breathe. Might have to adjust the y position of translate at the end of the CSS to position the submenu directly below the navbar.

Also is there a better way to make sure that the submenu appears directly bellow the navigation bar regardless of the height of the navbar?

Lastly, would it be possible to change the submenu's top arrow color to the same color that renders when you hover over the submenu options?

```css
/* ==========================================================================
                                Start of CSS reset
     ========================================================================== */

a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}:focus{outline:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:"";content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-results-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;resize:vertical}audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;max-width:100%}audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-size:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}a:focus{outline:thin dotted}a:active,a:hover{outline:0}img{border:0;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic}figure{margin:0}form{margin:0}fieldset{border:1px solid silver;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em}legend{border:0;padding:0;white-space:normal}button,input,select,textarea{font-size:100%;margin:0;vertical-align:baseline}button,input{line-height:normal}button,select{text-transform:none}button,html input[type=button],input[type=reset],input[type=submit]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer}button[disabled],html input[disabled]{cursor:default}input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}input[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-moz-box-sizing:content-box;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box}input[type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0}textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}button,html,input,select,textarea{color:#222}::-moz-selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}::selection{background:#b3d4fc;text-shadow:none}img{vertical-align:middle}fieldset{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}.chromeframe{margin:.2em 0;background:#ccc;color:#000;padding:.2em 0}html{font-size:62.5%}


/* ==========================================================================
                                End of CSS reset
     ========================================================================== */


/* ==========================================================================
                                Start of Nav 
     ========================================================================== */

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

#layout #main-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, right top, left top, from(#185a9d), color-stop(#185a9d), to(#58a3b2));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #185a9d, #185a9d, #58a3b2);
}

#layout #main-nav .nav-tabs-container ul li {
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
  display: inline-block;
}

#layout #main-nav .nav-tabs-container ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0.9rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#layout #main-nav .nav-tabs-container ul li.active>a,
#layout #main-nav .nav-tabs-container ul li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container>.header-menu-tab {
  outline: none;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container>.header-menu-tab:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #general-settings-btn,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #account-settings-btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  -ms-grid-row-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #general-settings-btn:hover,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #account-settings-btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.336);
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #general-settings-btn {
  width: 3.8rem;
  height: 3.8rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #general-settings-btn .svg-inline--fa,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #general-settings-btn .svg-inline--fa.fa-w-16 {
  width: 1.8rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #account-settings-btn {
  width: 4.3rem;
  height: 4.3rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #account-settings-btn #user-initial {
  width: 3.3rem;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 3.3rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #add-location-btn,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #select-location {
  height: 3.5rem;
  padding: 0 0.8rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container #select-location {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
  align-self: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu {
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 8rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 8rem);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu::before,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu::before {
  content: "";
  top: -0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  right: calc(50% - 0.6rem);
  border-width: 0 0.6rem 0.6rem 0.6rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu a,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #676666;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu a:hover,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu a .svg-inline--fa,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu a .svg-inline--fa {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container .tab-submenu hr,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container .tab-submenu hr {
  margin: 0;
}

#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .general-settings-container:hover>.tab-submenu,
#layout #main-nav .header-menu-container .account-settings-container:hover>.tab-submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 6.8rem);
  transform: translate(-50%, 6.8rem);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.02, 0.2, 0.97);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.02, 0.2, 0.97);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>



  <section id="layout">

    <nav id="main-nav">

      <!------------------------------------------------------ Nav tabs ------------------------------------------------------>
      <div class="nav-tabs-container">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a id="inbox-section" href="#">Inbox</a></li>
          <li><a id="contact-section" href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a id="phone-section" href="#">Phone</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-------------------------------------------- Header Menu -------------------------------------------->
      <div class="header-menu-container">

        <!-------------------------------------------- General Settings button -------------------------------------------->
        <span class="header-menu-tab general-settings-container">
                    <button id="general-settings-btn" title="General Settings"> <i class="fas fa-th"></i></button>

                    <span class="tab-submenu general-settings-options">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Placeholder 1</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Placeholder 2</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Placeholder 3</a>
                    </span>
        </span>


        <!------------------------------------------------------ Account settings button ------------------------------------------------------>
        <span class="header-menu-tab account-settings-container">

                    <button id="account-settings-btn" title="Account settings">
                        <span id="user-initial">B</span>
        </button>

        <span class="tab-submenu account-settings-options">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> Placeholder 4</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i> Placeholder 5</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="far fa-credit-card"></i> Placeholder 6</a>

                        <hr>

                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> Placeholder 7</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> Placeholder 8</a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Placeholder 9</a>
                    </span>

        </span>


        <!------------------------------------------------------ Add locations button ------------------------------------------------------>
        <span class="header-menu-tab">
                    <button id="add-location-btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add Location</button>
                </span>


        <!------------------------------------------------------ Select locations button ------------------------------------------------------>
        <span class="header-menu-tab">
                    <select id="select-location" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
                        <option value="0" selected="">Select Location</option>
                        <option>Location 1</option>
                        <option>Location 2</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways to solve this. first, you could say its good enough. second, you can toggle the CSS styling via `onMouseOver` javascript event and add a delay after the mouse leaves to create an elusion. and third, you can scrap the hover completely and work with the `onClick` event on the button/document.